# Creating nested object from multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've two arrays. One is for ideas and other is it's reviewer.

```
['idea1', 'idea2', 'idea3', 'idea4', 'idea5', 'idea6', 'idea7']
['reviewer1', 'reviewer2', 'reviewer3', 'reviewer4']
```

I need to generate a data-object from the above two arrays, to feed the same to the table. I need help in generating the object.

```
[ {
   fields: {
     "Idea": "idea1",
     "Reviewer": "reviewer1"
   }, fields: {
     "Idea": "idea2",
     "Reviewer": "reviewer2"
   }, fields: {
     "Idea": "idea3",
     "Reviewer": "reviewer3"
   },  fields: {
     "Idea": "idea4",
     "Reviewer": "reviewer4"
   },  fields: {
     "Idea": "idea5",
     "Reviewer": "reviewer1"
   },  fields: {
     "Idea": "idea6",
     "Reviewer": "reviewer2"
   },  fields: {
     "Idea": "idea7",
     "Reviewer": "reviewer3"
   }, 
}]
```

One reviewer will be assigned to many ideas but for any idea, there will be only one reviewer.

Comment: You have 7 ideas and only 4 reviewers. What needs to be done in that case? Please give us a complete example (no `...` in the expected result) and more details. Also, your end result is not valid. A single Object cannot have multiple keys with the same name `fields`. Only the last one would be kept, as it would overwrite the previous ones

Comment: There is no way to create an object in this format, because you are assigning the same key name to different objects

Comment: @blex, updated the expected result. thanks for looking into the issue

Comment: @AksJacoves, This is for the Airtable Scripting task, that I'm going to use the data for. FYI... https://airtable.com/developers/scripting/api/table#create-records-async

Comment: What you did was: `[{fields: {...}, fields: {...}}]` the correct thing is `[{fields: {...}}, {fields: {...}}]`

Comment: That is, you created several objects with the same name inside an object, the right thing would be that these various objects of the same name be in different objects

Comment: Airtable API accepts the format that I'm requesting for. Please check the link I've provided.

Comment: You don't understand what I'm saying. And yes, I saw the link you sent and it’s like I’m saying, it’s correct there but yours is wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216082/discussion-between-aks-jacoves-and-tinku).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
const idea = ['idea1', 'idea2', 'idea3', 'idea4', 'idea5', 'idea6', 'idea7']
const reviewer = ['reviewer1', 'reviewer2', 'reviewer3', 'reviewer4']

let ctr =0;
const res = idea.reduce((acc, val)=>{
 ctr= ctr=== reviewer.length? 0 : ctr;
 acc = [...acc, {"fields":{
  "idea": val,
  "reviewer": reviewer[ctr++]
 }}];
  return acc
},[])

console.log(res)
```

A better and simpler approach where you don't require to mutate `ctr`  is this

```js
var idea = ['idea1', 'idea2', 'idea3', 'idea4', 'idea5', 'idea6', 'idea7'];
var reviewer = ['reviewer1', 'reviewer2', 'reviewer3', 'reviewer4'];

var res = idea.map((idea, i) => {
  return {
    fields: {
      idea,
      reviewer: reviewer[i % reviewer.length]
    }
  }
});

console.log(res)
```

Comment: thanks for the solution!! :)

Comment: Consider getting rid of the first answer